# How can I display customer group id on page?

Tags: magento2, php

I am trying to use a formula that looks at whether a customer is wholesale or not, and then discounts the price automatically for a product if they are, but on a **custom priced product**. (So I can't just go to advanced pricing and set a tier price). In my formula, I have a variable setup like this

```
squareinchcost=>('customerGroupId' == 'wholesale' ? .39 : .58);
```

The 'customerGroupId' is what I need to figure out. What do I need to enter to have the formula actually pull the customerGroupId so that this can equate to either .39 or .58 depending on the customer group?

Comment: You want to get customer id on phtml ?

Comment: Yes. On a specific product page

Comment: Do you have any custom module on your website ?

Comment: yeah a custom math formula module for the product

Comment: What is the exact version of magento 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is for get customer group.
You can put in any file and call the function and it will be work.

```
/**
 * Customer Group
 *
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection
 */
protected $_customerGroup;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroup
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroup,        
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_customerGroup = $customerGroup;        
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
/**
 * Get customer groups
 * 
 * @return array
 */ 
public function getCustomerGroups() {
    $customerGroups = $this->_customerGroup->toOptionArray();
    array_unshift($customerGroups, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>'Any'));
    return $customerGroups;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How can I run this on just one product page?

Comment: One product page means? @Josiah

Comment: I just need to be able to call the function on a product page so that it will return whether a customer is a wholesale customer or not for my formula

Comment: Yes so when you will call this function you will get customer group label and you just need to check in if condition for that. @Josiah

Comment: Where can I put this function though so that it can be called on a product page?

Comment: can I just put this function on any page and then enter getCustomerGroups() to get the current group?

Comment: Yes it will fetch if the customer is login.

Answer (score 0):

To get the customer group Id, you can use this code.

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession) 
{
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function getCustomerGroupId()
{
    if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
        return $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
    endif;
}
```

Comment: How can I run this on just one product page?

Comment: You need to to put above code into your block file and then call that function into your phtml file.